# Is it possible a trigger on a select statement with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, triggers

I know that triggers can be used on insert, update and delete, but what about a trigger (or sort of) on a select statement. I want to use a trigger to insert data on a table B when it is selected an existent record on a table A, it could be possible?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a trigger, but you can:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunc(...) BEGIN INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(...) END;
```

And then

```
SELECT myFunc(...), ... FROM otherTable WHERE id = 1;
```

Not an elegant solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in the database itself.

However there are monitoring/instrumentation products for databases (e.g. for Sybase - not sure about MySQL) which track every query executed by the server, and can do anything based on that - usually store the query log into a data warehouse for later analysis, but they can just as well insert a record into table B for you, I would guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your application so that database access occurs only through certain methods, and in those methods, add the monitoring you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can write an application which will be monitoring the query log and doing something when a select occurs. A pretty crude way to solve the problem though...